# how to write sql query for calculate time different

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
I have table structure like this

EnrollNo,Date,Time

1, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 13:12 
1, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 23:14 
2, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 11:12 
2, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 20:14 
3, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 12:12 
3, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 23:14 
4, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 17:12 
4, 8-10-2011 12:00:32 , 23:14


Data Type for EnrollNo is int, Date is Datetime, Time is text

I want out put like below

EnrollNo, Date, TimeDiff, Timein, Timeout

1, 8-10-2011 12:00:32, 10:02 , 13:12, 23:14
2, 8-10-2011 12:00:32, 09:02 , 11:12, 20:14 
3, 8-10-2011 12:00:32, 11:02 , 12:12, 23:14 
4, 8-10-2011 12:00:32, 06:02 , 17:12, 23:14
```

Comment: @MarkByers datatype i mention in question already m using sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `(EnrollNo, Date)`, and use `min()` and `max()` to find the checkin and checkout times.  Using `datediff` you can find the time difference.

```
select  EnrollNo
,       [Date]
,       right('0' + cast(datediff(hour, cast(min(Time) as datetime), 
            cast(max(Time) as datetime)) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' +
        right('0' + cast(datediff(minute, cast(min(Time) as datetime), 
            cast(max(Time) as datetime)) % 60 as varchar(2)),2)
,       min(Time)
,       max(Time)
from    @t
group by
        EnrollNo
,       [Date]
```

Formatting is hard in SQL; the query would be much easier if you passed the time difference in seconds, and let the client application do the formatting.

[Full example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114632/)

Comment: @Andomar this is right but i am not getting my exact out put just i have difff. time in each row for single enrollno with date in column date

Comment: @Mark Byers: Missed that, added now

Comment: updated query give me following error ::Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Is your [date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259188(v=sql.80).aspx) set correctly?  F.e. `set dateformat mdy`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Select enrollNo, DateAdd(day, datediff(day, 0, date), 0) Date,
    Convert(varChar(5), Cast(Max(date) - Min(date) as DateTime), 4) timediff, 
    Convert(varChar(5), Min(date), 4) Timein, 
    Convert(varChar(5), Max(date), 4) Timeout
From @t
Group By DateAdd(day, datediff(day, 0, date), 0)
```

Comment: its give me following error ::  Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use datediff function in sql http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx
to find the difference from check in / out?